# try catch issues actionscript3 IOErrorEvent

Tags: actionscript-3, url, try-catch, flash

This is image share app written in as3. in my ftp there is a file "/Images" and images are inside of that. names are 1.jpg 2.jpg 3.jpg until 21.jpg .(21 images inside of folder). as you can  see there are 2 variable totalImages and imageNumber. I entered totalImages = 100.
when I click next button its going next page(next image. Starting 1.jpg). But when it comes image 21(last image),if I click next button i cannot pass image 22.(there is no 22.jpg).And I take this error on Output on Flash. Error #2044: Unhandled IOErrorEvent:. text=Error #2036: Load Never Completed. I want to use try catch method and see error inside of swf. but I dont know where i put try and catch in the code. Thank you in advance

```
import flash.display.Loader;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import fl.transitions.Tween;
import fl.transitions.easing.*;



//*****************CREATING VARIABLES*****************************//

//the array has all picture labels
//var myGlow:GlowFilter = new GlowFilter(0xffffff,1,10,10,255);// saving the glow
//var myShadow:DropShadowFilter = new DropShadowFilter(6);// saving the shadow to be applied later
var totalImages=100;
var imageNumber=1;
var myLoader:Loader = new Loader();


//************LOADING IMAGES TO STAGE********************//
//elearningau.com/nondynamic/
var myRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://www.elearningau.com/nondynamic/Images/"+imageNumber+".JPG");

myLoader.load(myRequest);
addChildAt(myLoader,1);// will be added under the buttons layer but over the texture


//************CENTERING THE PICS****************//

myLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.INIT, getImageInfo);
function getImageInfo(event:Event){
    myLoader.width = 485;
    myLoader.height = 360;
    var imgX=(stage.stageWidth- myLoader.width)/(-1)*(1/25);
    var imgY=(stage.stageHeight- myLoader.height)/2;
    myLoader.x=imgX;
    myLoader.y = imgY;// lines 37,38,39 & 40 are centering the loader formulae
    //myLoader.filters = [myGlow, myShadow];// adding a white color glow / grey shadow
    //var myTween:Tween = new Tween(myLoader, "alpha", None.easeNone, 0,1,2,true);//apply fade in

    }
//**************GOING TO NEXT IMAGE********************************//

rightButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, nextImage);

function nextImage(event:MouseEvent){

    if(imageNumber<totalImages)
    {
        imageNumber++;
    }
    else (imageNumber=1);
    reload();


}
//**************GOING TO PREVIOUS IMAGE********************************//

leftButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, previousImage);
function previousImage(event:MouseEvent){
    if(imageNumber>1)
    {
        imageNumber--;
    }
    else (imageNumber=totalImages);
    reload();
    }

//*****************RELOADING****************************//
//elearningau.com/nondynamic/
function reload(){
    removeChild(myLoader);
    myRequest= new URLRequest("http://www.elearningau.com/nondynamic/Images/"+imageNumber+".JPG");
    myLoader.load(myRequest);
    addChildAt(myLoader,1);// will be added under the buttons layer but over the texture
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the error handlers from your loader:

```
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onError);

function onError(e:IOErrorEvent):void {}
```

try/catch does not work with asynchronous events, and load is asynchronous.

Comment: Thank you.Then can you give me and advice? What sould i do? If I press nextbtn (21.jpg to 22.jpg but there is no 22.jpg) it will go back 1.jpg

Comment: Your `totalImages` equals 100. You should change that to 21. All the logic seems to be in place.

Comment: :) smart solution. But what if don't know how many images are there. I  asked try-catch because of this. If take Error #2044 then swap image 1.jpg